# Where to add FirebaseApp.configure() in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

So I am attempting to integrate Google's Firebase into my SpriteKit game and was having a small issue.

The instruction from Firebase is..."Configure a FIRApp shared instance, typically in your application's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:`FirebaseApp.configure()`".

Now I've located the file called AppDelegate.swift in my Xcode project but when I place it into the first function, which matches the named one in the instructions I get the following error `Use of unresolved Identifier FirebaseApp`.

And I remembered to import Firebase at the top of document. Any suggestions?

Comment: In Firebase 4.0.0, `FIRApp` was renamed to `FirebaseApp` so the correct initialization is now ` FirebaseApp.configure()`. The documentation was pushed earlier than the code was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is `FIRApp`, not `FirebaseApp`.

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

**Note:** Don't forget to `import` the `Firebase` module.

```
import Firebase
```

Comment: I remembered to `import` the `Firebase` module, but this seems to work the error has disappeared. Thank you for your help!

Comment: When I attempted to accept the comment as the answer it said I had to wait 10 minutes, so just did it now that I've logged back in

Comment: Oh my apologies, I am new to StackOverflow, I thought I could accept both answers as they both worked, I didn't realize it unaccepted the previous one (being yours). I have switched it back as you were the first person to answer with the correct solution.

Comment: It's ok mate it happens :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know though!

Answer (score 3):

Your app delegate needs to look something like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

Make sure you call `FIRApp.configure()` before the `return true` and remember to `import Firebase`.